# Move features in spatial objects in R

Tags: qgis, r, point, move

QGIS has a "Move Features" tool where points can be moved. Is it possible to move features from within R?

If not, is it possible to open R spatial objects in QGIS, move points in QGIS then import the spatial object back in R?

Comment: Do you mean to move features within R using a point-and-click interface?

Comment: Yes move features within R using a point-and-click interface

Answer (score 4):

Its a bit obscure, but the `elide` function in the `maptools` package can be used to move `sp` class objects.

This works for all point, line, and polygon classes. Following the data setup in `help(elide)` here's a river polygon shifted 0.10 units up and across:

```
> plot(rivers1)
> plot(elide(rivers1, shift=c(.10,.10)),add=TRUE)
> axis(1)
```

For `sf` objects adding a point to a geometry acts as a vector addition:

```
> nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
Reading layer `nc' from data source `/nobackup/rowlings/RLibrary/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/sf/shape/nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
epsg (SRID):    4267
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
```

Let's move the first county +1 degree up and across:

```
> nc$geom[[1]] = nc$geom[[1]] + st_point(c(1,1))
> plot(nc$geom)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Barry. I find this succeeds in moving the polygons, but when when I move all polygons in `nc` with the same offset (e.g. `+ st_point(c(1,0))`) the output of `st_bbox(nc)` does not change, even though the geoms do plot in the new positions. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way of building an interface in R to click and drag geometries to a new location, but probably it's just easier to load the layer in QGIS and modify it there before reloading in R. It will take only a few seconds to switch between apps and reload layers.

```
library(sf)
db <- "~/workspace/_temp/qgis2R.gpkg"

# Create a point layer

pts <- data.frame(name = "blue", x = 36.5, y = -2.5)
pts <- st_as_sf(pts, coords = c('x', 'y'), crs = 4326)
write_sf(pts, dsn = db, layer = "pts", driver = 'GPKG')
```

Open QGIS and add that point layer - plus (in this example) the "Stamen toner" layer from QuickMapServices

[image]

Edit the layer - move the point somewhere (or add new ones) then save the layer edits

[image]

Reload the layer in R - note the new XY data.

```
pts <- read_sf(db, layer = "pts")
pts

Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 36.8635 ymin: -2.832009 xmax: 36.8635 ymax: -2.832009
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  name                 geom
  <chr>             <POINT>
1 blue  (36.8635 -2.832009)
```